# How change color of Background Status Bar Of Android

Tags: android, statusbar

How change color of Background Status Bar of Android?
I try change color of background of Status Bar of Android for build Unity3d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change Status Bar Color you should check that the user has Android APIv21 or higher and then

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP;) {
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#FAFAFA")); 
}
```

Comment: I try this, buy I get error: the method setStatusBarColor(int) is undefined for the type Window.  My eclipse project contains android-support-v4.jar

Comment: So you are not building neither working with newest API 21/22 build tools